# RSelenium fails to findElement when not called individually

Tags: r, click, rselenium

(Apologies for the bad title, improvements are welcome)

When I run the three last lines of the code below *individually* everything works as expected. It finds the "Primary Data" tab and clicks on it.
But my purpose is to put this inside a function, where it does not work.
The problem can be reproduced by simply running the three last lines together.

```
require(rvest)
require(rJava)
require(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", verbose = FALSE)
remDr<-driver[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.bexis.uni-jena.de/ddm/data/Showdata/31215")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value= "primarydata")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was as simple as interposing a `Sys.sleep`. This works:

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.bexis.uni-jena.de/ddm/data/Showdata/31215")
Sys.sleep(1)
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value= "primarydata")
webElem$clickElement()
```